# How to perform Gaussian elimination to invert a matrix if the matrix contains zeros on the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I'm coding the method that inverts a matrix through Gaussian elimination. I've coded everything assuming that there are no zeros on the diagonal.

For the situation where a diagonal element is zero, what should I do? It's certain that some matrices with zero on the diagonal are still invertible, so how should I invert them by Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Try interchanging rows.

Comment: @ChrisLeary  If I interchange rows of a matrix and then invert it, would the result equal to the invert of the original matrix??

Comment: It is a mistake to focus only on the effect of exchanging rows of $A$.  Please review my Answer, and note that the elementary row operations of "Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting" are applied to the augmented matrix $[A|I]$.  Any sequence of elementary row operations that transform $A$ into the identity $I$ will simultaneously transform the identity matrix $I$ into the inverse $A^{-1}$ of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an "augmented matrix" of the form $[A|I]$ and use elementary row operations to put this into reduced row echelon form.  The result will be $[I|A^{-1}]$ if $A$ is an invertible matrix.

---

Let's do an example, mainly for the benefit of future Readers.  The OP mentions a "method [to] invert a matrix through Gaussian elimination ... assuming that there are no zero on the diagonal."  It follows that the code already implements two of the three elementary row operations, multiplying a row by a nonzero scalar and adding (equiv. subtracting) a multiple of one row to (from) another row.  What else is needed when we confront a zero "on the diagonal" (i.e. in a matrix position where we want a leading one) is the operation of exchanging two rows.

Using this operation does not "break" the matrix any more than do the other two kinds of elementary row operations.  Yes, it changes the matrix, but the key here is that we *want* to change a matrix into its reduced row echelon form.

In particular the goal of inverting matrix $A$ will be achieved by finding the reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix $[A|I]$.  The required form can be found by an algorithmically determined sequence of elementary row operations, but the sequence is not unique.  When no row exchanges are used, the method is called "Gaussian elimination without pivoting".  This is possible precisely when the leading principal minors are nonzero, as this is another way of saying that zeros will not appear "on the diagonal," where we want the reduced row echelon form to have leading ones.

That is, elimination algorithms which use row exchanges commonly call those steps "pivoting".  How hard one works to choose the "pivot" row is subject to a tradeoff in numeric stability, but in what follows we will present the case of [partial pivoting (PDF)](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~neela/partialpivot.pdf).  This amounts to taking the columns in whatever order they are presented (full pivoting meaning a strategy that might introduce leading ones in a wider consideration of all columns not yet reduced).

For our example we take:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Thus the augmented matrix we will reduce is $[A|I]$:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

A reasonable rule when a zero appears where a leading one is wanted is to swap the row with the zero and one below it with an entry of largest maximum absolute value in the same column.  Here we immediately start with a zero in the $(1,1)$ position, and below that both entries in that first column have the maximum absolute value $1$.  So let's exchange the first and the second rows:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

It is unnecessary to "scale" the leading entry in the current row (we already have a leading one). We proceed to clear the entries below it using addition/subtraction of a multiple of the first row to each other rows:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

Having reduced the first column, we turn our attention to the second column.  Fortuitously the $(2,2)$ entry is already a leading one in that row, and we proceed to add multiples of that second row to clear out the other entries in the second column:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & \textbf 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

Finally we scale the leading entry in the third row, so that the $(3,3)$ value becomes a leading one:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \textbf 1 & 1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2
\end{bmatrix} $$

Adding multiples of this new third row allows us to zero-out the other entries in the third column:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
 0 & 0 & \textbf 1 & 1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now we have the reduced row echelon form, $[I|A^{-1}]$.  To verify we can multiply:

$$  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \;
 \begin{bmatrix} -1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2 \end{bmatrix} = I $$

Comment: OP's question is what to do when $0$ is encountered on the main diagonal and pivoting on it is not possible

Comment: @gt6989b: Pivoting is precisely what one needs to do to put a nonzero entry into the current column and row.  If the entries at that position and below it in the current column are all zero, THEN one *cannot* produce a leading one there and the matrix is not invertible.  However an exchange of the current row with one below it is an elementary row operation and should succeed in producing a nonzero entry provided the matrix is invertible (up to floating point precision).  All this is standard in an undergraduate discrete math or linear algebra class.

Comment: @hardmath  If I interchange rows of a matrix and then invert it, would the result equal to the invert of the original matrix??

Comment: @hardmath  We need the invert of the original matrix. The invert of the permuted matrix is not what we need. Is there a relationship between the 2 inverts then?

Comment: That's what I showed you above.  When you obtain the reduced row echelon form of the matrix $[A|I]$, using any sequence of elementary row operations including as necessary row exchanges, the result will be $[I|A^{-1}]$ whenever $A$ is an invertible matrix.

Comment: @hardmath  Thank you for your answer. I have implemented the code that computes the reduced row echelon form thru elementary row operations. I think I am just confused that if row exchange is performed (hence breaking the original matrix) , then we are not getting the inversion of the original matrix by the end of the process.

Comment: Row exchanges are needed during Gaussian elimination if a zero appears in a diagonal entry, but as long as the same row operations are applied to the right-hand side of the augmented matrix as to the left-hand side, nothing is "broken".  For clarity you should give the reference you are using for Gaussian elimination in the body of your Question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90941/discussion-between-kid-learning-c-and-hardmath).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks a lot!